# Trying to make form have a rainbow option but wont work

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to make it to where you press a checkbox the color of the top of the MetroFramework style will change but It is only changing the color of the checkbox. I am also trying to make it so it just keeps changing so you don't have to click it multiple times but I cant seem to find a way to make it work.

Code used:

```
    Dim m = New Random()
    Dim s = m.Next(0, 13)
    MetroStyleManager1.Style = DirectCast(s, MetroColorStyle)
    MetroStyleManager1.Style = DirectCast(s, MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color changes auto after checkbox tick, then you should use timer() 
For e.g. on checkbox check a timer1.start() and on timer.tick() enter your code: // 
On checkbox uncheck call method timer1.stop().

The color will only change then when checkbox is checked with every second(depend on interval). Without click multiple times.